# Protocol extension vs class extension in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Assume there is a protocol `Draggable`, usually will be conformed by an `UIView` object

```
protocol Draggable {
  drag()
}
```

We can either implement `drag()` in a protocol extension as `option 1`

```
// option 1
extension Draggable where Self: UIView {
  func drag() {
    // implementation
  }
}
extension UIView: Draggable {} // added after @Rich Tolley's answer
```

Or we can implement `drag()` in a `UIView` extension as `option 2`

```
// option 2
extension UIView: Draggable {
  func drag() {
    // implementation
  }
}
```

### Here is my question:

- Is there a difference between these two approaches (option 1 & option 2) ?
- If yes, what's the difference and how to choose when we design a our project or library ?

**And idea** would be helpful.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is a difference: (EDIT: or at least there was in the original version of this q, which didn't add `extension UIView : Draggable {}` to the end of option 1).

- Option 1 creates a default implementation for instances of `UIView` that conform to `Draggable`. You still need to mark `UIView`s you wish to conform to `Draggable` as such in the declaration: `class MyView : Draggable`. Anything that conforms to `Draggable` but is not a `UIView` subclass will need to supply its own implementation.
- Option 2 extends *all* `UIView`s to make them conform to `Draggable`. Nothing else can be a `Draggable` unless separate extensions are also written for those classes, or they are manually conformed to the protocol.  There is no need to add `Draggable` in the class declaration.

The protocol extension is usually the better option. In this case this is obviously true since not all `UIView`s can be `Draggable`. Also, going down the protocol extension route means that you can create a `Draggable` object that is not a `UIView` subclass, if necessary (admittedly fairly unlikely, since most Cocoa controls are `UIView` subclasses - although not all -`UIBarButtonItem` isn't, strangely)

If you follow option 2, you will be adding unnecessary methods to `UIView` in a  lot of cases, which is a violation of good object oriented design - specifically the Interface Segregation Principle (clients should not be forced to rely on methods they don't use
) - which is the 'I' in the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Comment: Thank you for replying. My bad, I forgot to put `extension UIView: Draggable {}` into option 1. Is there still a difference technically between option 1 & 2 if I add this?

Comment: No, they'd be the same. I'd prefer the original option 1, for the reasons stated above.

Answer (score 3):

A protocol extension should be used when you want to implement functionality for more than just one class. 
In this case you should use the `extension UIView: Draggable` as the Implementation is specific to the UIView class.

Assuming you have a protocol which provides location:

```
protocol Location {
    var location: CGPoint { get set }
}
```

and you want every class which implements Location to conform to Draggable, then a protocol extension could be used:

```
extension Draggable where Self: Location {
    func drag() {
    }
}
```

For further reference, you should have a look at [Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-408/) from the 2015 WWDC.